# Counting Up and Down using Volume buttons on iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Hi I creating an app for myself, where I want to count and display the # on the screen. I want to use the volume buttons to count up and down. I was able create a button on screen to count up and down but I want to use the physical buttons. I have listed what I have so far, but the volume buttons doesn't seem to work. I've replaced AVAudioSession with AVAudioPlayer hoping to control the volume with the slider. **I get a error EXC_BAD_ACCESS  (Code=1, Adress=0x48)**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var counter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tapCounterUp: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tapCounterDown: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tapReset: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var volumeController: UISlider!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
    }
    
    //Starts the count at 0
    var count : Int = 0
    
    //Adds +1 to Count
    @IBAction func buttonUp(_ sender: Any) {
        count += 1
        counter.text = String(count)
    }
    
    //Subtracts -1 to Count
    @IBAction func buttonDown(_ sender: Any) {
        count -= 1
        counter.text = String(count)
    }
    
    //Resets the Count to "0"
    @IBAction func buttonReset(_ sender: Any) {
        count = 0
        counter.text = String(count)
    }
    
    //Volume Controller
    @IBAction func volumeControl(_ sender: UISlider) {
        
        let sliderValue = lroundf(sender.value)
        counter.text = "\(sliderValue)"
            
            /// **This is were the Error occurs.**
            audioPlayer.volume = volumeController.value
    }
    // End of function, don't delete
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `listenVolumeButton`?

Comment: I don't know where to call the lustenVolumeButton to. Should I print in the label? (This is my first time using swift)

Comment: If you don't call it it's not going to run, you can start by calling it in your `viewDidLoad` (just to see if it works) and then change it later to better suit your needs

Comment: Is there a volumeController in your storyboard? Check in the debugger if it’s nil.